# Hand flute on Shabbat

Tags: halacha, shabbat

What is the law of playing a [hand flute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hand_flute) on Shabbat/Yom Tov?

Comment: Should it be anything different than whistling or clapping?

Comment: @Kazibácsi in general/intuitively, yes, in halacha, I don't know. Probably not, but would be nice to see if discussed

Comment: Wouldn’t it be like drumming with your hands on a table?

Comment: @Chatzkel That involves another object, that's why I haven't mentioned it.